# Joomla manual restoring from Cpanel

Tags: joomla2.5, cpanel

I have a Joomla website being hacked and when I restore, the front end is ok but at the backend none of the components of joomla is working, any link I click I get to the same interface for uploading which is not from joomla, 
Could anybody help me solve this issue or in updating joomla via cpanel without being logged in joomla backend?

waiting to hear from you guys

Answer (score 0):

You should download Joomla Patch File and also take backup of old files and directory where current joomla has installed. and follow below steps.

1. Open up your FTP client
2. Log in to your website
3. Navigate to the the folder where Joomla is actually installed
4. Upload the patched Joomla installer into the folder
5. Open your cPanel window
6. Go back to the “File Manager”
7. Navigate to the patched Joomla installer you uploaded via FTP, and check the box next to it.
8. Click extract
9. After a few seconds the files should be extracted
10. Lastly, login to your Joomla admin, refresh the page and the version number should be updated.

For further or more detail you can go through [this link](http://withoutink.com/technology/how-to-upgrade-a-joomla-website-with-cpanel/).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this step

1   Open Your cpanle

2   Log in

3   goto softeculous link

4   then, you can updating joomla via cpanel